# Can "doubler" be used to express the idea of "getting one up on someone" without any negative connotation?

Tags: vocabulaire

In conversation, I just said:

> Je n’aime pas trop que l’on me **double**, mais si cela peut rapprocher XXX de son objectif, alors je suis de tout cœur avec toi.

Here I have the idea of "someone getting one up on me" promotion-wise -- without resorting to any underhanded method, I might add.

I picked up this particular (figurative) usage of "doubler" somewhere along the line, but I can't seem to find a dictionary entry anywhere that perfectly matches this interpretation, so I'm not sure this usage is considered correct. I wonder if it might not be misconstrued as "trahir".

Comment: Unless there is context you don't provide, this is bound to be ambiguous: "overtake (as with a car)" or "double-cross".

Comment: @LPH I'm starting to get weary of saying the same thing. Not sure what you are trying to prove to me by fussing over typos, but if you spot obvious typos, feel free to edit them without waiting for confirmation. Especially when it comes to a trivial typo like this that has nothing to do with French and no one else pays attention to. When you leave a comment, please stick to what's relevant to a given question.

Answer (score 1):

D'après [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/doubler/26576?q=doubler#26448) :

> Passer devant un véhicule alors qu'on était derrière, effectuer un dépassement : *La voiture a doublé un cycliste.*
>
> Trahir quelqu'un, le devancer dans une opération en recueillant les profits qui devaient lui revenir.